# iOS Application Unit Testing with Core Data, and Magical Record

Tags: ios, core-data, ocunit, magicalrecord

I have an iOS app that uses Core Data along with the excellent [Magical Record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) to manage persistence. Here is my problem:

Our existing Unit Testing structure uses the standard iOS application tests. I want to run my unit tests with a clean in-memory db for each test. I followed the directions in [this article](http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/15/unit-testing-with-core-data/) to set that up using Magical Record. The issue comes up in the implementation of running application tests. Because application tests run the application bundle first, then the unit test bundle, my normal call to set up the core data stack is being called before my in-memory store call has a chance to run.

I googled this issue all night, and found a couple of promising articles:

- http://blog.goosoftware.co.uk//2013/02/07/unit-testing-a-coredata-manager-class/
- [How to use Core Data for Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880739/how-to-use-core-data-for-dependency-injection)

The problem with these is that they are using a singleton data access object as a gateway into their core data calls. My app is not set up this way. I am using calls into Magical Record to do my data fetching and saving.

Has anyone run into this issue? If so, am I missing some detail that would allow me to swap out my data setup to an in-memory store when my tests are running?

**EDIT: Adding code**

In my app delegate, I have this:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    [MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack];
    // Other setup code
    return YES;
}
```

In every unit test class that deals with core data, I have this:

```
-(void)setUp{
    [super setUp];
    [MagicalRecord setDefaultModelFromClass:[self class]];
    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore];
}

-(void)tearDown{
    [MagicalRecord cleanUp];
    [super tearDown];
}
```

I can see that both the app delegate code and setup/teardown are called for each test, but I'm not sure how to make the default core data stack for the tests use the in memory store. I also have the .xcdatamodel file added to the unit test target.

Comment: Is there some sample code you have or project settings that can help narrow this down? I think you are missing one thing, but I have no idea what it is with out seeing what you're doing.

Comment: @casademora - Added code to illustrate how I'm doing things. I also use CocoaPods to pull in Magical Record, not sure if that might have anything to do with the issue.

Comment: hrm, do you need to be running application tests? In this case, you need to not use the test setup. If you're using logic tests, then the setup specified in the blog post works fine. Also, I hate that there's a distinction between application and logic tests :/

Comment: @casamedora good point about the application tests. I was trying to go path of least resistance on this, but I might have to bite the bullet and add logic tests to the project. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @MarkStruzinski did you end up going w/ logic tests in the end?  I've just ran across this issue myself...

Comment: I did. App tests just simply don't work in this use case. After that, I was up and running. Stinks to have to create a new test target, but once it's done, everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, the problem is that even after calling `[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore];` in `setUp` tests are accessing real data store?

I've ran into same issue when writing my unit tests for objects responsible for database interaction and with little debugging, I think I've found an issue.

`[MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack];` in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` is called earlier than `[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore];` in `setUp`. And if we look how creating core data stack by MagicalRecord acutally works, we'll understand what's the problem.

```
+ (void) setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore;
{
    if ([NSPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_defaultStoreCoordinator] != nil) return;

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_coordinatorWithInMemoryStore];
    [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_setDefaultStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

    [NSManagedObjectContext MR_initializeDefaultContextWithCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```

`[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_defaultStoreCoordinator]` is not nil at the point of setting up in-memory store and that makes above method to silently return without doing anything. And at that point you are left with your real data store instead of in-memory store. Solution is simple. Just call

```
[MagicalRecord cleanUp];
```

before calling in `[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore];` in `setUp` to tear current data stack and really set up in-memory store so it should look like this:

```
- (void)setUp{
    [super setUp];
    [MagicalRecord setDefaultModelFromClass:[self class]];
    [MagicalRecord cleanUp];
    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore];
}
```